# python multi-list add element with for loop

Tags: python

i want to add an element to a multi-list,like this

```py
l = [["0"]*5]*5
print(l)
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i].append("\n")
```

but why every child-list in multi-list add 5th '\n'

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']]
```

I want only add an element.

Comment: could you provide an example of what you want your list to look like?

Comment: The list `l` includes 5 references to the same list. So with every access to `l` you are modifying the same list

Answer (score -2):

Your list length is 5. That's why it is appending the 5th \n.

Comment: Yes but the OP is doing `l[i].append("\n")` so supposedly each sub-list should have ***one*** `\n` which is why the OP is asking...